# How to write WP_query for the post ids in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WordPress and I am trying to write a loop query to fetch the posts using post_ids.

Please find the below code I have tried.

```
$current_query = new WP_Query(
    [
        //'post_type'   => 'snippet',
        'post__in' => $postids,
    ]
);
```

When I am trying to print the query and the post category it is taking as post but I want some specific category when I add the same in the array args it is giving me other query which is giving null. Can some one help me on this?

Comment: _Show us_ what you actually added where (code), instead of giving us the vague descriptions.

Answer (score -1):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'snippet',
    'post__in' => array(123, 345, 678)
);

$postsbyid = get_posts($args);

foreach ($postsbyid as $postbyid) :
    //Do something
endforeach;
```